# App doesn’t work properly on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I created an app and it’s live in Google Play. I constantly test it to eliminate bugs and crashes. The app is almost crash-free. But sometimes I receive bad reviews from my users (only Samsung devices users) (1-2% of Samsung devices). They say that the app opens but displays a screen with app title and gets stuck on it (I don’t even have such screen in my app).

I am not receiving any crash reports or ANR reports about something that can be related to this issue. I tested on all Samsung devices I could find (friends, relatives, hired people on Upwork) but everything just works fine.

Is there anything that can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somewhere in your code does not work on those devices or there is an exception you caught but forgot to log it.
Try analyzing your logs and use some services like Microsoft Appcenter to find out which part of your app does not work properly.